# How to store complex objects in jQuery / data attributes within Razor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, custom-data-attribute

In my Razor markup, I am looping through my model collection and outputting table rows. Currently, I am storing the the item ID's in each table row's "data-id" attribute. I am needing to store the entire object per row though so it will save me some future ajax calls. What is a good way to store the full object per row on the Razor output for my jQuery to use later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using something like [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) or any other model-based template Javascript language (there's plenty, including Backbone, Angular, etc)? You could simply bind your whole model to Javascript (serialize it to JSON). You could then use a template to generate the table. This is the best advice I can give you.

If you want a quick/hack-ey way, you could always do something like:

```
<script>
var dataMap = {};
</script>

@foreach(var item in Model.Whatever) {
 <tr data-id="@item.Id"> ... etc </tr>
 <script>
dataMap['@item.Id'] = @Json(item); // you'd have to make a Html helper to do this
</script>
}
```

Comment: -1, the user is obviously using .Net MVC... Telling them to use knockout.js is silly and makes no sense. They need a solution for this problem. You are suggesting they change their entire architecture.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a hidden field that has the encoded json String and you can then parse the jSon on demand in your javascript code. have an hidden field per row according to your requirement..

```
@foreach(var item in Model.Whatever) {
 <tr data-id="@item.Id"> ... etc </tr>
 <input type="hidden" val="@Json(model)" />
}
```